# Symfony2: How to assign values before calling $this->render()?

Tags: php, oop, symfony, events, twig

`myMethod()` renders a template with some default parameters assigned. I'd like to assign some values usable within the twig-template before calling the logic by extending `ParentController`.

I added the line of pseudocode `$this->assignValue('myKey', 'myValue');`. Does anyone know if there is a method like `assignValue()` or how to solve my issue?

Thanks in advance!

```
class ParentController {
    protected function myMethod() {
        return $this->render('myTemplate.html.twig', array(
            'param1' => 'value1',
            'param2' => 'value2',
            'param3' => 'value3'
        ));
    }
}

class ChildController extends ParentController {
    // TODO: Assign some parameters BEFORE

    // Pseudocode:
    $this->assignValue('myKey', 'myValue');
    // /Pseudocode 

    return parent::myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just redefine `render` in your ChildController method somehow like:

```
function render($tpl, $parameters) {
   $parameters = array_merge($parameters, ['myKey' => 'myValue']/** or some other parameters*/);
   return parent::render($tpl, $parameters);
}
```